# Count the sum of a subset of the index in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas.core.series.Series with some data, now I want to calculate the sum of the index 0 to 13. How would I do that?

**This is what tried so far:**

```
#preg.prglngth.value_counts().sort_index()

prglnght_var = preg['prglngth']
prglnght_var.ser[:14]
```

**The series data looks like this:**

```
0       15
1        9
....
47       1
48       7
50       2
Name: prglngth, dtype: int64
```

Comment: need `print (prglnght_var.ser[:14].sum())` ?

Comment: `prglnght_var.ser[:14].sum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
prglnght_var.loc[:14].sum()
```

`.loc` is a method of the series class.
It selects the rows or columns (the rows, in this case) for the criteria you choose (in this case, all lines from 0 to 13)
It returns a series

`.sum` is a method of a series that will sum all values in it.
As the series is already filtered for the lines you want, it will sum all values that you want.

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Just realized I was doing something that I disliked in others answers. Thanks : )

Comment: Thank you @edinho! `preg.prglngth.value_counts().sort_index().loc[:13].sum()` gave me the right result